# Error: child pid 6695 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I use django + mod-wsgi + apache to develop a website. and it is strange that when i launch the website it's ok for all other function expect for login in function. when i try logging in, it gives me a 500 error.

This is the error form error_log:

```
[Sat May 21 13:00:39 2011] [error] /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Authentication backends without a `supports_object_permissions` attribute are deprecated. Please define it in <class 'accounts.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend'>.
[Sat May 21 13:00:39 2011] [error]   DeprecationWarning)
[Sat May 21 13:00:39 2011] [error] /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py:31: DeprecationWarning: Authentication backends without a `supports_anonymous_user` attribute are deprecated. Please define it in <class 'accounts.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend'>.
[Sat May 21 13:00:39 2011] [error]   DeprecationWarning)
[Sat May 21 05:00:39 2011] [notice] child pid 6693 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat May 21 05:00:39 2011] [notice] child pid 6695 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Please advise me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation for common causes:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Apache_Process_Crashes
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues

Try and track it down by using a debugger:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB

Most likely your login page causes an extension module to be imported and used that doesn't work in sub interpreters. Try forcing that application to run in the main interpreter using:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

See documentation on the mod_wsgi web site for more details.