# Mod_wsgi worker processes segmentation fault (11)

Tags: django, apache, segmentation-fault, matplotlib, mod-wsgi

I am having a problem with my django application, which is hosted with apache/mod_wsgi. I added some matplotlib code into the application, and apache worker processes now crashing.

I reduced this problem to the following:

- Without any matplotlib imports application works ok
- when "import matplotlib" is added anywhere in the application, worker processes die with segfault and users see no reply from server
- "import matplotlib" works just fine in commandline python interpreter - segfault happens only in apache processes

Here is the log entry:

```
[Tue May 24 08:29:08 2011] [notice] child pid 17576 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I cannot reproduce problem on other computer.
I tried to remove (rm site-packages/matplotli*) and install different versions of matplotlib (0.99.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1)
I tried to install all modules in virtualenv and point to virtualenv from my .wsgi script.

I tried this: 
[Error: child pid 6695 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079726/error-child-pid-6695-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11)
I read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ as well.

Any pointers on how to debug/workaround this issue will be much appreciated.

(I am even ready to move to any other server (paste/cherrypy + apache mod_proxy, etc.) to eliminate the problem.)

Here are my apache settings:

**/usr/sbin/httpd -V**

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr 10 2010 11:21:07
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.10
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

**/usr/sbin/httpd -l**

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

**/usr/sbin/httpd -M**

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_alias_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_default_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 ldap_module (shared)
 authnz_ldap_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 usertrack_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 speling_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

**Apache config**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName              somesite.com
    DocumentRoot            "/somedir"

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /somedir/production.wsgi

    <..>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the wiki you said you read, you should have found:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB

As a side note, it is recommended you do not use prefork/embedded mode. User mod_wsgi daemon mode if you are forced to use prefork MPM. Read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html

for some of the reasons why.

Other people have got matplotlib working with mod_wsgi, so not obvious straight away what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks Graham, much appreciated. Though I was unable to debug crashes with GDB (I cannot turn off this particular server and cannot reproduce the issue on different computer), I will try this and post results if any. I use cherrypy + mod_proxy as a workaround.

Comment: If you use daemon mode of mod_wsgi you don't need to turn off the whole server. You just attach gdb to pid of the daemon process as documented and then trigger request to cause failure.