# Python Django httpd - [notice] child pid XXXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: python, django, apache

Sometimes it responds like a charm, but sometimes I got the error "No data received". I searched around but nothing worked. The posts which are suggesting the use of "`gdb`" to debug the apache for possible errors, well, I do not have the chance to test it with gdb, because in the server I'm working on, there's not any development softwares or libraries (except python), and I cannot install them. And the other half of the posts suggest the solutions which are compatible with webservers working with PHP - I don't know whether it makes any difference to the problem or not.

My httpd configuration is like this:

```
Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) DAV/2 
mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8b 
mod_jk/1.2.15 
PHP/5.1.6 
mod_wsgi/2.1-BRANCH 
Python/2.4.3 configured
```

I use Django, and hence mod_wsgi. Is there any other way for debugging this issue rather than using gdb?

Note that, in the previous versions of my application, I didn't get any error like this, never. For the newer versions, I didn't change the technology, just upgraded Django to 1.3, started using ZSI 2.1 on CentOS5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103386/mod-wsgi-worker-processes-segmentation-fault-11 mentions the different way apache is compiled could be causing problems. I suggest looking into that answer further if nothing else shows up.

Comment: Also, give this answer a look over: http://serverfault.com/questions/167069/run-mod-python-with-mod-wsgi-on-apache-for-django-segmentation-fault-11

Comment: I also wouldn't be surprised if it's the version of python you're using. Try installing python 2.7 (not the system python), and rebuilding mod_wsgi with the new python. Also disable mod_python if it's configured to load within apache.

Comment: Have you read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Apache_Process_Crashes and eliminated those possibilities mentioned there and also in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues ? Especially conflicting shared library versions with PHP and Python extension modules that will not work in a sub interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

As Graham-Dumpleton commented above, it seems to be a **well known issue** in `mod_wsgi`, namely with the `expat` library version compatibility.

The reason for the failure (as well as the steps to solve it) are [described here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IssuesWithExpatLibrary)

### tl;dr solution (from the link above):

> Note that this only applies to Python versions prior to Python 2.5.
>   From Python 2.5 onwards, the copy of the "expat" library bundled in
>   with Python is name space prefixed, thereby avoid name clashes with an
>   "expat" library which has previously been loaded.